# Converting object to date and then compare it

Tags: powershell

my purpose is to get a report specifically for a date (yersterday).
I have this type of object:

```
@odata.type       : #microsoft.graph.anonymousIpRiskEvent
id                : ////////
riskEventStatus   : active
riskLevel         : medium
riskEventType     : AnonymousIpRiskEvent
riskEventDateTime : 2018-10-16T08:45:16.3264945Z
closedDateTime    : 
createdDateTime   : 2018-10-16T09:52:05.0144201Z
userId            : /////////
userDisplayName   : ////////
userPrincipalName : ////////
ipAddress         : ////////
location          : ////////
```

I obviously have more events in the object called $event and all I want to do but I'm not able to is a if: for every event into $event, if the createdDateTime has been created yersterday, then put it on an object.
I'm able to make my custom object and export that later, but I can't really figure out how to make a compare of the date with the getdate.adddays(-1).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` will keep the current local time of day. To compare with yesterday 00:00:00 use `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date`

Comment: the best way to get "yesterday" is to compare it to midnight. this is done with `[datetime]::today` you could also do `if ([datetime]$event.createdDateTime -lt [datetime]::today -and -ge [datetime]::today.adddays(-1)) {do this}` this will only grab yesterdays logs.

Comment: @RobertCotterman the syntax is wrong and it shows me Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a `datetime` object before you can compare it. It's already in a format that should allow it to be converted by just casting it to the `[datetime]` type. E.g:

```
if ([datetime]$Event.createdDateTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-1) {
    ..
}
```

If you want to filter based on this property you could do:

```
$Events | Where-Object {[datetime]$_.CreatedDateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the `Where-Object` ... (+1)

Comment: The filter doesen't work, it still shows me events from any day

Comment: The current filter should show you any events older than 1 day. If you want to get just events from the previous day, you likely need to do something like `$Events | Where-Object { [datetime]$_.CreatedDateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -and [datetime]$_.CreatedDateTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) }`

Comment: If I use the first solution with the if it shows this error:
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime".

Comment: That will likely be because $Event is a collection of objects vs being a single object. Where as using Where-Object filters each object in a collection individually.

Comment: Filter with `Where-Object` as I described in my comment above.